# Get the first half of the string stored in the variable called phrase

Tags: python

Доброе!

Начинаю изучать python. Не могу понять одну задачу:

len() function is used to count how many characters long a string is.
Get the first half of the string stored in the variable called phrase.
Remember about string slicing

Код:

```
phrase = """
It is a really long string
triple-quoted strings are used
to define multi-line strings
"""
first_half = type here
print(first_half)
```

Куда копать?

Comment: @chemtech, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Копайте сюда:

```
first_half = phrase[:len(phrase)/2]
```

Но есть нюансы. Как считать половину, если количество символов нечетное? У вас строка начинается с символа перевода строки, учитывать его или нет и т. д.

Comment: Спасибо. Понял теперь. Эта задачка из PyCharm Educational Edition http://habrahabr.ru/company/JetBrains/blog/242103/

Comment: Чтобы код работал как в Питон 2 так и 3: `len(phrase) // 2` можно использовать.

Answer (score 0):

Перевод задания: len() - функция, которая используется для нахождения количества символов в строке. Найдите первую половину строки, сохраненной в переменной phrase. Вспомните о разбиении строки.

Т.е. вам надо строку разбить на две части и первую часть поместить в first_half

Comment: Примерно так и понимал...

Answer (score 0):

Нужно сделать преобразование типов, для того чтобы получить целое число, так как  len() отдает значение с плавающей запятой **int(len(phrase)/2)**

Правильный ответ

```
phrase = """
It is a really long string
triple-quoted strings are used
to define multi-line strings
"""
first_half = phrase[:int(len(phrase)/2)]
print(int(len(phrase)/2))
print(first_half)
```

Вывод

```
44.0
44    
It is a really long string
triple-quoted st
```

Задача кстати из [PYCHARM EDUCATIONAL EDITION](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm-educational/) - бесплатной программы для изучения Python, от известной компании JetBrains, советую ее всем кто хочет изучить основы Python.
Вот кстати [все задания](https://github.com/JetBrains/pycharm-courses/tree/master/introduction_course) из PYCHARM EDUCATIONAL EDITION

Comment: если нужен целый результат, то можно использовать просто: `len(phrase) // 2` (или `round(f)`, `math.ceil(f)`, `math.floor(f)`, etc в зависимости от того, какой результат необходим).